# Logic Structures: structures union is not a structure example

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Find a case, where:
>
> M is a structure, $M_1, m_2 \leq M$ are substructure,    yet $|M_3| =
>  |M_1| \cup |M_2 |$,  $M_3\leq M$ is not a substructure.

I have no idea.

Comment: Hint: do you know any linear algebra, or any group theory? If your first-order language is the language of group theory, or that of linear algebra (over some fixed field), what does this question ask?

Comment: well i guess that in linear algebra, if there are 2 vector spaces above a field, there union might not be vector space since the multiplication result may not be in the union of the 2 vector spaces?

Comment: This is pretty close, but not quite. What is an example of a structure in the language of vector spaces (over $\mathbb R$, let's say)? What are examples of substructures?

Comment: over $\mathbb(R)$, (0,1),(1,2) are substructures.

Comment: over $R^2$, x+y=0, x+2y=0 are substructures

Comment: No, those are elements and formulas respectively.

Comment: As much as I understand, a structure is a set of numbers, which may have defined functions\relations upon. What am I missing?

Comment: That is close to true: the set need not consist of numbers, it can consist of anything. Can you give some examples of structures?

Comment: a vector space is a structure

Comment: What's a concrete example? And, can you give examples of substructures of that concrete example? Note: substructures need to be structures in their own right.

Comment: Over the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ there are the substructure ${0}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^2 $

Comment: Exactly: the substructures are the subspaces. Can you think of more? Can you find two subspaces whose union is not a subspace?

Comment: Over the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, the vectorspaces $x+y=0, x-y=0$ are vector spaces, and their union is not a subspace, unless their union is their span?

Comment: I misunderstood you earlier. Yes, you're right. No, their union is their union.

Comment: Thank you very much! you have helped me tremendously